# Scrapy - LinkExtractor does not extract links from "yield" (ed) Requests?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is an example of a rule i'm using

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='(http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/.*_reviews.*-page-\d+\.html)'), follow=True, callback="parse_data")
```

Although This extracts the matching links from the `start_urls` It does'nt extract matching links within a page as a `yield request` at some point in the spider code.

Is this the normal way scrapy functions?

Comment: Could you show the complete code of your spider? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're using a CrawlSpider, Scrapy will apply the rules to every request.  The problem is likely elsewhere.